# Can't Create ActiveX Object

Tags: asp-classic, payment-gateway

I am using third party payment gateway for my site.

Once customer fills amount detail and contact detail, page will be redirected to other .asp page.

In that asp page ,i have written below code.

```
    Dim pipe

    Set pipe = Server.CreateObject("e24PaymentPipe.e24PaymentPipe.1")


    pipe.ResourcePath=resourcePath  'mandatory 
    pipe.Alias=aliasName            'mandatory 
    pipe.Action=action              'mandatory 
    pipe.ResponseURL=receiptURL     'mandatory 
    pipe.ErrorURL=errorURL      'mandatory 
    pipe.Amt=amount                 'mandatory 

    pipe.Currency=curr
    pipe.Language=language
    pipe.TrackId=trackId

    pipe.Udf1=donateamt
    pipe.Udf2=email
    pipe.Udf3=phone
    pipe.Udf4=baddress
    pipe.Udf5=fname
```

But i am getting error at 2nd line only .
The error says , Can't create Activex Object.

I have successfully registered e24paymentpipe.dll, but still i am getting error.

Can anyone please help me..?

Comment: look in registry HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT - find if there is e24PaymentPipe.e24PaymentPipe, check what CLSID is associated and find this CLSID - check it is points to proper dll

Comment: What's in the windows logs? You need to check there to see if there are any more diagnostics pertaining to the fail. Personally the first thing I would do is to try and see if I can execute the code manually in vbscript (using cscript.exe) and then try and work out why the COM Server is not instantiating.

Comment: Which server are you on? Is IIS running is 32-bit mode? Did you register the component in 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @AardVark71 IIS is running in 32 Bit mode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally found my answer.
I did register both dlls (e24payment.dll and e24pipe.dll).
And also check application pool.

In application pool, go to Advanced setting and check that Enable 32 bit application is set to false and that's it.

It worked like a charm.

Comment: Wow, I wish I had found this post much earlier!  Although in my case, the "Enable 32 bit applications" setting was already set to false and I needed to set it to true.

Comment: Weird... I had this issue and just had to change it to True (the opposite of your advice) and my application now works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

### IIS 10, example with missing 32-bit 'adrot.dll', used in ASP Classic.

This approach can be applied for another 'old' 32-bit dll-s.

1. Open installation CD(or DVD, iso, etc.) of Windows XP.
2. Be assure of, that folder 'X:\i386'('X' is drive letter)
   contains file 'adrot.dl_', where 
   'dl_' means that this file is compressed 'dll'.
3. Open **CMD as administrator**.
4. Expand(decompress) 'adrot.dl_' to 'adrot.dll' by
   command in CMD :

   **X:\i386> expand ADROT.DL_ D:\ADROT.DLL**
5. Copy/Cut ADROT.DLL to C:\Windows\SysWOW64,
   because ADROT.DLL is 32bit component and must to be in 'SysWOW64'.
6. In CMD navigate to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and register dll :

   **C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32 adrot.dll**
7. In **IIS**, from left pane('Connections'), open(double click) 'Application Pools'
8. Find your **Application Pool**(by column 'Name').
9. Right click over name of your Application Pool and open 'Advanced Settings'.
10. In 'Advanced Settings', set '**Enable 32-Bit Applications**' to '**true**'.